# Не видит данные скрипта, который наследуется от другого (scriptableobject) C# UNITY

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю инвентарь. Есть основной скрипт Item, где указаны основные общие параметры предметов. От него наследуется скрипт Equipment, в котором указаны параметры, присущие только отдельным предметам (чтобы удобнее было создавать различные типы) и реализуется он через ScriptableObject. После создания предмета я пытаюсь обратиться к параметру (который есть только в скрипте Equipment) через Item - но мне пишет, что в Item нет таких переменных! Т.е. получить я могу только те переменные, которые хранятся именно в Item, а все, что в Equipment я не вижу, хотя он наследуется от Item. Как же мне тогда получить нужные мне переменные?

Comment: Намёк: лучше один раз показать, чем 10 раз рассказать.

Comment: По коду: наследовать equipment от item - немного не правильно. item - штука, equipment - совокупность штук.  Это как отнаследовать автомобиль от колеса))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да я это и сам понимаю, просто получается что я обращаясь к машине хочу получить данные колеса, а оно не дает. Вот и спрашиваю - как это сделать тогда правильно?

Comment: Нет, вы ничего не поняли. ............ а как сделать: читайте намёк

Comment: @АлексейШиманский так что именно я неправильно сделал то? Item - это базовый класс с основными параметрами, а Equipment - имеет все то же, что и Item + свои отдельные параметры, поэтому и наследуется от него - по-моему все логично?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это называется **инкапсуляция**, при апкасте к родительскому классу, все состояния и поведение дочерного скрывается.
Насчёт решения, можешь пробывать даункастить объект обратно к Equipment. Допустим так:

```
if (object1 is Equipment equipment)
    equipment.нужные_поля
```

Comment: Ну или как то более лаконично это сделать, я условно написал

Comment: Написал как лаконичнее

Comment: _Это называется инкапсуляция_ - нет, вы инкапсуляцию с наследованием перепутали. Не надо так. Это разные, никак не связанные друг с другом термины ООП.

Comment: Это называется даункастинг - нашел уже и ниже напишу как я сделал, хотя Ваш вариант тоже работает, спасибо! :)

Comment: @aepot почему же это не инкапсуляция, в данном случае она выражена сокрытием поведений и состояний класса от которого мы приводимся к базовому. Кажется это называется сокрытие реалезации

Comment: @aepot и я не перепутал инкапсуляцию с наследованием в том числе из за контекста, где автор вопроса говорил об "исчезновение" полей производного класса

Comment: @aepot и соответственно все парадигмы между собой связанны

Comment: @Gilly инкапсуляция к наследованию не имеет никакого отношения. Вы никак не сможете модификаторами доступа оставить член класса доступным после апкаста если его нет у родителя. 2 большие разницы. Инкапсуляция делается не апкастом, она вообще про другое. А связаны термины ООП именно самим ООП. То что член класса становится недоступным при апкасте, это особенность наследования, а не инкапсуляции. Эта особенность говорит о том, что его именно нет у родителя, а не то что он скрыт. Утверждение что "инкапсуляция - это сокрытие" ошибочно, у меня один кандидат, сказавший это, собеседование не прошел.

Comment: @aepot ну я к вам собеседоваться и не собираюсь, я с вами не согласен, но последующие аргументы врятли вас переубедят и будят повторяться. Так что удачи

Comment: @Gilly конечно не переубедят, ведь у вас их нет. Не надо со мной соглашаться или не соглашаться, надо найти умную книжку по основам ООП, а лучше 2 от разных авторов, чтоб наверняка, и вдумчиво почитать.

Comment: @aepot вы слышком агрессивный

Comment: @aepot есть пример таких умных книжек по ООП?

Comment: @Gilly вам кажется, мне просто лень в сообщения смайлики втыкать. :) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/373567

Answer (score 2):

```
Item foo = new Equipment(); // условно
foo.slot // "Item" не содержит определения "slot"
```

`Equipment` наследуется от `Item`, но не на оборот, поэтому с чево бы `Item` знать не то что о полях `Equipment`, а вообще о существовании этого класс.

```
if (foo is Equipment efoo)
    rightSlot = efoo.slot == targetSlot;
```

Comment: Да я это и сам понимаю. Надо найти просто как сделать обратный ход и получить все таки данные нужные. Ваш вариант либо не работает, либо я что-то не правильно понял..

Answer (score 0):

Вариант выше оказался правильным, только я сделал немного по другому и это называется даункастинг (Downcasting):

```cs
// item это производная от Item
Equipment equipment = (Equipment)item; //Downcasting
int needstat = equipment.damagePoints; //damagePoints - это один из параметров у Equipment
```

Всем остальным тоже спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Стоит иметь в виду, что если в Item будет лежать не Equipment, а другой тип наследника, в данной реализации вы получите исключение `InvalidCastException`.